# Drawing text in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am having a hard time drawing text in LibGDX. Every time I run it, i get a black window. I want the text to be white, but I dont see anything. I have tried finding numerous tutorials and vieos, and still cannot get it to work. I do have a vaild fnt and png file in my assets folder / fonts.

```
package org.alexwebber.frc.stalk;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    public class HelloWorld implements ApplicationListener
    {
        private SpriteBatch batch;
        private BitmapFont  font;

        @Override
        public void create()
        {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/main.fnt"),
                            Gdx.files.internal("fonts/main.png"), false);
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose()
        {
            batch.dispose();
            font.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void render()
        {
            batch.begin();
            font.setColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f);
            font.draw(batch, "Hello World", 25, 160);
            batch.end();
        }

        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void pause()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void resume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try `font = new BitmapFont();` instead? Also, `1.0f` should be sufficient for all four color values, instead of `255.0f`.

Comment: @JamesSkemp same result, nothing

Comment: I created a dummy page in an application and it worked fine, although I was implementing `Screen`. I'll try creating an empty project and see if I can replicate it. I think I have an idea, but ...

Comment: Thank you; this is the first time I saw what would happen when I didn't clear the screen in `render()` and it was amazing :)

Answer (score 4):

Something that might be impacting you is the removal of the screen clearing:

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    font.draw(batch, "Hello world", 25, 160);
    batch.end();
}
```

You can also try passing `Color.WHITE` as above. If the Android device you're using has an extreme screen resolution you may not be seeing the line of text.

Testing via [a Desktop application](http://strivinglife.com/words/Post/Configuring-a-libGDX-project-to-run-as-a-desktop-application-in-Android-Studio) may be a good idea as well, as you can tweak the screen resolution so the text is a larger size.